# About a directional derivative in "Numerical Optimization" by Jorge Nocedal and Stephen J. Wright.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I am reading "Numerical Optimization" by Jorge Nocedal and Stephen J. Wright.

I don't think that $D(||x||_1 : p)$ always exists.

Am I correct or not?

[image]

Comment: You are correct. The authors seem to neglect the fact that $\varepsilon$ can tend to zero by either positive or negative values.

Comment: I think the authors aren't *incorrect* but rather have failed to explicitly state the requirement that $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: @PierreCarre Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: @Rahul Thank you very much for your comment. I didn't notice that the authors' definition of directional derivatives is different from a usual definition.

Comment: @Rahul The requirement $\varepsilon > 0$ is not standard in the definition of a directional derivative, so this is really a major flaw. If they are not using a standard definition they should have great care in writing it down.

Comment: I would see the point of this definition if the authors had called something other than "directional derivative", for example "derivative along a vector".